# Integrate much faster if function split in two pieces

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following function

```
f1[x_,y_] = 1/( x^9 y (x^2 + y^2)^10) (1215 x^19 y + 144865 x^17 y^3 - 72524 x^15 y^5 + 587340 x^13 y^7 + 486330 x^11 y^9 + 465990 x^9 y^11 + 280500 x^7 y^13 + 109900 x^5 y^15 + 25375 x^3 y^17 + 2625 x y^19 + 2625 (x^2 + y^2)^10 ArcTan[y/x])
```

and I want to compute $\int_{x_0}^{+\infty}f_1(x,y) dx$ for $y>0$ and some real $x_0>0$. So, I define the following `$Assumptions`

```
$Assumptions = y > 0 && x0 > 0;
```

and compute

```
Integrate[f1[x, y], {x, x0, +\[Infinity]}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

With this command, Mathematica seems to be stuck and it does not return the result. However, if I slipt the function `f1[x,y]` in two pieces as

```
f2[x_, y_] = f1[x, y] // Collect[#, ArcTan[y/x], Simplify] &
```

and compute

```
Integrate[f2[x, y][[1]], {x, x0, +\[Infinity]}] + Integrate[f2[x, y][[2]], {x, x0, +\[Infinity]}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

I get the right answer in only 6seconds

```
(*Out: {5.82698, (1/(x0^7 (x0^2 + y^2)^9))(135 x0^16 + 13280 x0^14 y^2 + 1572 x0^12 y^4 + 39680 x0^10 y^6 + 35610 x0^8 y^8 + 26400 x0^6 y^10 + 12100 x0^4 y^12 + 3200 x0^2 y^14 + 375 y^16) + (25 (105 x0^7 y - 35 x0^5 y^3 + 21 x0^3 y^5 - 15 x0 y^7 + 105 (-x0^8 + y^8) ArcTan[y/x0]))/(8 x0^8 y^9)} *)
```

What is the reason?

Comment: With complicated expressions the algorithm may not find a form that it knows how to handle. Subdividing the expression provides simpler forms that it can handle. Your approach can be shortened using `Map`, i.e., `Integrate[#, {x, x0, +\[Infinity]}]& /@ Collect[f1[x, y], ArcTan[y/x], Simplify]`